Performance Issue with @sap-cloud-sdk/http-client
I am using Node.js version 20 and the @sap-cloud-sdk/http-client to make POST requests, but I am encountering APIs performance issues. However, when using Node.js version 18 with sap-cf-axios, the performance is better, and I receive APIs responses more quickly.
Can I improve this in Node 20?
Note: We are using Cloud SDK library: @sap-cloud-sdk/http-client and it function executeHttpRequest to send request to convergent mediation system (on-premise ) via cloud connector. The connectivity is made using Destination which is maintained in BTP sub-account and same for  sap-cf-axios.
Function -1
const httpclient = require('@sap-cloud-sdk/http-client');
async function callSoapApi(data, req, res) {
    await httpclient.executeHttpRequest(
        {
            destinationName: destination
        },
        {
            method: 'POST',
            url: req.url,
            data: data,
            headers: {
                SOAPAction: "SOAP ACTION NAME"
            }
        },
        {
            fetchCsrfToken: false
        }
    ).then(response => {
        res.status(200).send(response.data);
    }).catch(error => {
        generateErrorMessage(req, res, error);// Separate function for error handling
    });
}

Function -2
let SapCfAxios = require('sap-cf-axios').default;

let callSoapApi = async (data, req, res) => {
    try {
        let axios = SapCfAxios("Destination_name");
        let dataResp = await axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: req.url,
            data: data,
            headers: {
                SOAPAction: "SOAP ACTION NAME", // Replace with your SOAP action
            }
        });
        res.status(200).send(dataResp.data);
    } catch (error) {
        generateErrorMessage(req,res,error); //Separate function for error handling
    }
}

When using Node.js version 18 with sap-cf-axios, the performance is better, and I receive APIs responses more quickly. but I want to use this package @sap-cloud-sdk/http-client

Answering this question given the setup is rather hard, as you are both using different dependencies and different node versions, you are also not describing what kind of performance issue you are facing.
To answer, you will need to 1) compare both clients under the same node version, e.g. use both with node 18 or 20 and 2) describe what kind of performance issue you are facing.
